# Why do I keep getting a type mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba

The asterisks indicate where the error is occuring
Below is he code that I am using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = Range("Item_ID").Row And _
    Target.Column = Range("Item_ID").Column Then
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    
    'Set IE.Visible
    ie.Visible = True
    
    ***ie.navigate "https://portal.shiptrackapp.com/Admin/reports.aspx?records=" & Range("Item_ID").Value***
    
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document
    Dim odd As String
    odd = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("odd")(1).innerText)
    ie.Quit
    Dim aodd As Variant
    aodd = Split(sodd, ",")
    Range("Tracking_Number").Value = aodd(3)
    Range("Item_ID").Value = aodd(0)
    Range("pick_up_date").Value = aodd(2)
    Range("Delivery_Status_Date").Value = aodd(3)
    Range("Time").Value = aodd(4)
    Range("Delivery_Driver_Name").Value = aodd(5)
    Range("Status").Value = aodd(6)
    Range("Stats_des").Value = aodd(7)
    Range("Comments").Value = aodd(8)
    Range("Signed_By").Value = aodd(9)
    Range("Del_Add").Value = aodd(10)
    Range("History").Value = aodd(11)
    Range("Transaction_ID").Value = aodd(12)
    Range("ScanCode_dt").Value = aodd(13)
    Range("Company_Name").Value = aodd(14)
    Range("Def_loc_id").Value = aodd(15)
    Range("Dri_cmmts").Value = aodd(16)
    Range("creation_dt").Value = aodd(17)
    Range("scan_type").Value = aodd(18)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Item_ID` a single-cell range?  What does it contain?

Comment: `ie.navigate ` requires a string as parameter. `Range("Item_ID").Value` is of variant data type. If the cell is formatted as `General` Excel will convert its `Value` to either string, date, number or boolean. You can probably solve this problem by specifying that you need a string, like, `& CString(Range("Item_ID").Value)`.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, Item_ID is a single-cell range. The contents of the cell is set to change depending of the information that is being looked up.

Comment: @Variatus I added your suggestion to the line in question, however, I received a compile error of sub or function not defined. Please help. The new line looks like this: ie.navigate "https://portal.shiptrackapp.com/Admin/reports.aspx?records=" & cString(Range("Item_ID").Value)

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @Variatus  I added your suggestion to the line in question, however, I received a compile error of sub or function not defined. Please help. The new line looks like this: ie.navigate "portal.shiptrackapp.com/Admin/reports.aspx?records=" & cString(Range("Item_ID").Value)

Comment: Sorry, the function's correct name is `CStr`.

Comment: @Variatus I got the type mismatch error once again even after I changed the line to ie.navigate "https://portal.shiptrackapp.com/Admin/reports.aspx?records=" & CStr(Range("Item_ID").Value)

Comment: Replace the cell reference with a hard value, just in case the cause is elsewhere. If that works, tell us the hard value you used and examine you cell value for leading or trailing blanks.

Comment: @Variatus I keep getting the type mismatch error. If possible, can you show me what the code is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may have modelled your code on [this site](https://www.guru99.com/data-scraping-vba.html), where the syntax appears 100% identical with yours.

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim ecoll As Object
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set doc = ie.documen
```

The line of code that gives the trouble has a concatenated string. I suggested you eliminate that and try your code with a hard-coded string as shown above. If that works the problem must be caused by the concatenation: either the variable read from the worksheet or the concatenation syntax itself. Please do the first test first.

I don't use IE myself. Here is working code I use every day. Note that the argument `HTMLdoc` is a return object. It is passed to the function empty, the function fills it up and the calling procedure receives it back.

```
Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal Site As Nur, _
                    HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, _
                    Optional Secty As String) As Boolean
    ' NIC 003 ++ 10 Aug 2020
    ' return Not True if the site couldn't be reached

    Dim URL         As String
    Dim Response    As String
    
    URL = StoredURL(Site, Secty)
        ' URL is a string like "https://portal.shiptrackapp.com/Admin/reports.aspx?records=MAA12345"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False                 ' not asynchronous
        On Error GoTo NoURL
        .Send
        Response = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set HTMLdoc = New HTMLDocument
    HTMLdoc.Body.innerHTML = Response
    GetHTMLDoc = True
    Exit Function
    
NoURL:
    Msg.InfoBox "NoURL", 0, vbInformation, URL    ' this is a MsgBox
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

You may like to google for the "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" object to find code that handles the HTMLdocument. Basically, "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" connects to the Internet without the use of a browser. However, changing the system shouldn't solve your problem because that lies with the variable `URL` (in my code) which you will need in whichever system you deploy. Therefore I recommend that you try your existing code without the concatenation.

To take this one step further: If the hard-coded string also fails then the problem might be with the IE. You may have to load a reference library (DLL) to use it. In that case the surprise would be that no error occurs at  `ie.Visible = True` or even `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer` and the possibility of using another system appears in a new light.